# Why is being a hybrid a curse?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-vampire-diaries

In Vampire Diaries S02E21 and also a few near-by episodes, it is said that Klaus is cursed - as he is both a Vampire and a Werewolf and more powerful than both.

How is it a curse and not a blessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vampire Diaries Wiki](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid):

> Hybrids are **obligated** to serve *Klaus* because his blood created them and they feel loyal to him because he freed them from the pain of turning every full moon. *They have limited free will, along with lack of control.*

This lack of control and their susceptibility to mind-control is a **curse** which only hybrids have.

**EDIT:** In light of OP's edit, narrowing down the discussion to Klaus only, the possible explanation is the worst of both the species - Vampires and Werewolves. The thirst for blood, as well as the pain of turning into a wolf.

Comment: But Klaus doesn't has it right. He is not cursed.

Comment: You are correct, Klaus is exempt from the curse as he is the **first hybrid**.

Comment: And my question is particularly about Klaus.

Comment: Ya I can see that the *edit* specifies that now!

Answer (score 1):

It's called a curse because the original witch (his mother) did a spell on him to suppress his  werewolf part. At the end of season 2, he broke the curse. He could turn freely thereafter and the the curse no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

It's a curse because he has the disadvantages of both. He thirsts for blood while suffering the effects of turning into a Wherewolf.

Answer (score -1):

All the ups are pretty snazzy but the downs are pretty bad as well. Also you would have to serve ***KLAUS***, which isn't the best thing to be doing considering how many people wanna kill him. If you can break the ***sire bond*** you still need to control your thirst for blood. Let's just remember back to what Tyler had to do to break the sire bond. Lots of pain involved. *Unless you love pain and Klaus yep its a curse.*